# Reduction to Basis algorithm as universal statement

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, universal-property

In the book "Linear Algebra Done Right" ( Sheldon Axler ), the basis reduction algorithm ( Proof ) is as follows:

[image]

**To practice mathematical writing, I tried to write the algorithm in a similar fashion using my own understanding in the following manner:**

Let $ B = \{ v_1,...,v_n \} $ be an arbitrary spanning set of $ V $ . For all $ v_i \in B $, where $ 
1 \leq i \leq n $, we'll check whether $ v_i $ is a linear combination of the other vectors in $ B $, if yes then we'll delete $ v_i $ from $ B $ else if not, keep $ v_i $ in $ B $.

**Note:** My proposal of the algorithm can be written logically as ( not fully formal, but it's mostly for intuition ): $\forall \text{spanning set $ B=\{ v_1,...,v_n \} $ } . \forall v_i \in B ( 1\leq i \leq n ) . P(v_i)  $
.
where I denote the statement " check whether $ v_i $ is a linear combination of the other vectors in $ B $, if yes then we'll delete $ v_i $ from $ B $ else if not, keep $ v_i $ in $ B $ " as $ P(v_i)$

Is my proposal of writing the algorithm correct? is it equivalent to the algorithm in the book?

Comment: Using your proposal, the set $B = \{(1,0), (1,1), (0,1)\}$ spanning $\mathbb{R}^2$ would result in the empty set (every vector in $B$ can be written as a linear combination of the others, so every vector would be removed).  It's important at each step that we only consider the previous vectors the algorithm has considered, not all of $B$.  (related: also note that if $B$ is a set, we may have a problem with "deleting" elements from $B$ and calling the result $B$ as well)

Comment: $ ( 1, 0) = (1,1) - (0,1) $ so it is removed from B.  Then we're left with $ B = \{ (1,1) , (0,1) \}  $  and neither of these two vectors can be written as linear combination of the other, so why would they be deleted?